# How to make such lines near text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to describe them, so here is a screenshot
[image]

Comment: I would flag this question but I reached my daily limit. So I answered it :D

Comment: We need your attemps! please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: what have you tried? pseudos + display:xx , no pseudos but background gradients?etc... :)

Comment: It would help if you posted a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of a picture. I can't view the image since it is blocked through a proxy on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one method using css pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`.

I used the Horizontal bar Unicode character ― in the css `content:` declaration.

```css
div:before {
  content: "― ";
}

div:after {
  content: " ―";
}
```

```html
<div>TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the code

```css
p {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: max-content;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
hr {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
    top: 9px;
}
div {
postition: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```